# Replace all occurences of a substring with elements of a list

Tags: python

I'm having trouble solving a little problem with python:

I have a string that contains substrings, whose amount is equal to the amount of elements in a list of other strings. I want to replace these substrings with the elements of the list. A minimal example of what my code looks like right now would be:

```
import fileinput
#this string is in the text file "file_containing_string1"
string1 = "text substring text substring text substring text" 
list1 = [element1, element2, element3]

...

with fileinput.FileInput(file_containing_string1, inplace = True, backup = ".bak") as file:

    for element in list1:

        for line in file:
            print(line.replace("substring", element), end = "")
```

The output that I want to obtain would be:

```
"text element1 text element2 text element3 text"
```

The ouput that my code produces:

```
"text element1 text element1 text element1 text"
```

I have tried out a lot of different ways to get to where I want to be and have googled solutions to this problem but have not encountered any. I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Is using string format is an option?

Comment: @balderman I do have to store the text in a file eventually but before that, yes, working with string format would be possible

Comment: working with string format. `s = ''My string. replace {} and replace {} ".format(lst[0],lst[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solution using .format method of string which is pretty short:

```py
string1 = "text substring text substring text substring text" #this string is in the text file "file_containing_string1"
list1 = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3']
string2=string1.replace('substring','{}')

print(string2.format(*list1))
```

Comment: This seems to work on my minimal example, though fails to provide the same result on my real code. I'll have to look into why it behaves that way but thank you so much for your contribution!

Comment: I made it work, the problem was due to the string then being passed to the text file, but that's resolved now. Thank you so so much for your help, this was a very simple and elegant solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the strings one after the other.

```
import fileinput

string1 = "text substring text substring text substring text" #this string is in the text file "file_containing_string1"
list1 = [element1, element2, element3]

...

with fileinput.FileInput(file_containing_string1, inplace = True, backup = ".bak") as file:

    for element in list1:

        for line in file:
            line = line.replace("substring", element, 1)
            print(line, end = "")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that modifying the code in this way still yields the same result though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all limit the occurrences of the substring you want to replace, using the `count` parameter of `replace()` string method:

```
  line.replace("substring", element, 1)
```

Then you have also invert the two *for-loop* and move the `print` in the outer one, so:

```
for line in file:
    for element in list1:
        line = line.replace("substring", element, 1)
    print(line, end="")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this still yields the same result as my approach

Comment: @1337_N00B i don't think so :) try again and let me know (be aware that after each execution you have to replace the content of *file_containing_string1* with the original one)

Comment: I really can't seem to make this work any other way, always stays the same.

Answer (score -1):

First change the order of the loops, and add count to replace

```
file = [
    "line 1: text substring text substring text substring text\n",
    "line 2: text substring text substring text substring text\n",
]
list1 = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3']
for line in file:
    for element in list1:
        line = line.replace("substring", element, 1)
    print(line,end="")
```

The output:

```
line 1: text element1 text element2 text element3 text
line 2: text element1 text element2 text element3 text
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had tried this before, unfortunately this now prints the resulting string three times. That is to say the result looks something like this "text text text element1 element2 element3 text text text element1 element2 element3 text text text element1 element2 element3 text text text"

Comment: If you want to display the each line only once, move it the print to the outer loop.

Comment: This in turn would yield the same result that I had from the get-go, meaning that only element1 would be printed